# java.sql.SQLException: Inconsistent java and sql object types: SYS.XMLTYPE

Tags: spring, oracle, jdbc, spring-data, xmltype

Trying to read data from XMLTYPE column using spring jdbc

Declaration 
`@Autowired
  OracleXmlHandler sqlXmlHandler;`

Object Read as string
`sqlXmlHandler.getXmlAsString(resultSet, "xml_column")`

getting the following exception : 

`Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Inconsistent java and sql object types: SYS.XMLTYPE
    at oracle.sql.OPAQUE.toClass(OPAQUE.java:395) ~[ojdbc6-11.2.0.4.jar:11.2.0.4.0]
    at oracle.sql.OPAQUE.toJdbc(OPAQUE.java:333) ~[ojdbc6-11.2.0.4.jar:11.2.0.4.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.NamedTypeAccessor.getObject(NamedTypeAccessor.java:193) ~[ojdbc6-11.2.0.4.jar:11.2.0.4.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.NamedTypeAccessor.getObject(NamedTypeAccessor.java:123) ~[ojdbc6-11.2.0.4.jar:11.2.0.4.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleResultSetImpl.getObject(OracleResultSetImpl.java:1108) ~[ojdbc6-11.2.0.4.jar:11.2.0.4.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleResultSet.getObject(OracleResultSet.java:462) ~[ojdbc6-11.2.0.4.jar:11.2.0.4.0]
    at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrappedResultSet.getObject(WrappedResultSet.java:1199) ~[?:?]`

pom.xml has the required entries for xdb6,xmlparserv2,spring-data-oracle,spring-oxm

Tried other alternatives with out spring-jdbc as well.

Any insights will be really helpful.

Comment: What does your query look like? Can you show us the table specification also?

Comment: `getJdbcTemplate().query("Select xml_column from xmltable where id = ? ", args, new ResultSetExtractor<>(){}`

following the guide at : http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-jdbc/docs/1.2.0.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#orcl.xmltypes

Comment: Your column name needs to be xml_text not xml_column if you're following that tutorial.

Comment: i believe the column name can be any thing for select

Comment: The column name needs to match the name of the column in the table. So you'll need to look at the table definition for xmltable and match that in your select query. Unless you changed it from the spec in the table, you need to have "select xml_text from xmltable where id = ?". You can alias the column by using "select xml_text as xml_column from xmltable" but you still need to reference the column by it's name.